# How to call a predicate that appends two lists in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, append, call, predicate

Everywhere I look I see something like this: `append([1,2,3],[a,b,c],appended).`,
but what if I have 2 lists : `ok([1,2,3]).` and `hello([a,b,c]).` and I want to append `ok` and `hello` together.

Why does `append(ok,hello,appended).` not work?

How would I do it that way without having to manually type in every element if the lists are already defined?

Comment: Why do you expect `append(ok,hello,appended)` to work? `append(X, Y, Z)` simply appends the *lists* `X` and `Y` to a list `Z`...

Comment: ok well I want to call the result something different and so I want it to be called appended which is ok and hello appended together. How do I do that without having to type each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first query the lists, then append them:

```ml
ok( OK), hello( Hello), append( OK, Hello, Appended).
```

Prolog's logical variables names *must* start with Upper Case letters.

If you want to see only `Appended` reported as the result of your query, try

```ml
ok( _OK), hello( _Hello), append( _OK, _Hello, Appended).
```

Another, less hackish way to accomplish this, as suggested in the comments by [Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity), is to define a special-purpose predicate for that,

```
appended( Appended) :-
  ok( OK), hello( Hello), append( OK, Hello, Appended).
```

Comment: do I test it by doing `member(OK, Appended).` where OK is an element of ok  ? Because it returns false when I do that.

Comment: you write exactly as I show. try `ok(OK).` on its own. does it work? you claimed it is already defined, so it should work. does it?

Comment: and what about `hello(Hello).`? it should also work. then, the expression shown in the answer should too. if not, please show your query and the response that you get.

Comment: It works but when I do the query above, it prints OK then Hello and then Appended. I want it just to print Appended.

Comment: Try `solve(Appended) :- ok(OK), hello(Hello), append(OK, Hello, Appended).` And then query for `?- solve(Appended).`. That should just print `Appended`.